# How to ask cmake to take relative path for a source file?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, wine

Currently, I am developing a CMakeLists.txt which will compile my source code for both Linux and Windows. I am using GCC compiler for Linux and Microsoft visual studio compiler for windows. I'm using Cmake in Linux. Since MSVS is windows compiler my using wine to run it on a Linux machine. 
    I am facing a weired issue with respect to the source file path. I'm adding my source files as follows.

```
project (APP_SRC C)
set (SRC_DIR "../src")
set (APP_SRC ${SRC_DIR}/../../dir1/main.c
     ${SRC_DIR}/../../dir1/file1.c
     ${SRC_DIR}/../../dir2/file2.c
     ...)

ADD_LIBRARY(APP_SRC SHARED ${SRC_DIR})
```

I am expecting Cmake to take a relative path for all my source file, But for some reason, it is taking an absolute path. Since I am using Microsoft visual studio as my compiler and linker, **cl.exe expects source file path to starts as Z:/ or C:/**. **But source file path starts as "/home/Abhi/...". So Cl.exe simply throws an error as missing source filename.**

cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/home/Abhi/Documents/Application/src/main.c'
cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename

How can I ask CMake to pick up a relative path instead of an absolute path? This will help with cross-platform compilation. How can I tackle this issue?

Thanks and Regards,
Abhishek Naik.

Comment: When building on wine, do you use [Visual Studio generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html#visual-studio-generators) or something else? Do you manually redefine a compiler (with `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` setting)?

Comment: Yes, I have manually redefined a compiler to be Microsoft visual studio compiler as explained in the following link
https://github.com/eruffaldi/wine_vcpp

Comment: Referred project describes several possible ways. Please, add to the **question post** details how do you build your project: which patch you have applied, which toolchain you use, which parameters you have passed to CMake and so on. See also [ask].